# Can event.persist() cause memory leaks?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code:

```
onFieldChange(e) {
    let selectionStart = e.target.selectionStart;
    let selectionEnd = e.target.selectionEnd;
    this.state.selectionStart = this.inputBox.current.selectionStart;
    let value = this.formatNumber(e.target.value);
    e.persist();
    this.setState({value}, () => {
        e.target.selectionStart = selectionStart
    });
}
```

Can e.persist() cause a memory leak and if so how do I free it manually? And where does this method come from since I can't find documentation for it anywhere.

Comment: It just has a small [note in the `Event Pooling` section of the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling). What are you trying to achieve? You should not mutate state directly like `this.state.selectionStart`. It's better to manipulate state with just `setState`.

Comment: I'm trying to access e.target.selectionStart from the `this.setState()` callback.

Comment: Then you can take out the target from the event before the `setState` call, and use `target.selectionStart` in the callback. This way the event doesn't have to be persisted. `const { target } = event; this.setState({ value }, () => target.selectionStart = 'something');`